# My wordpress multisite homepage redirects to signup page

Tags: redirect

So I just setup my website `fightify.com` and as you will see, visitors are automatically redirected to a signup page, which shouldnt be happening.

This only occurs if the domain is typed without the www. prefix. `www.fightify.com` yields no errors.

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the .htaccess file, but I'm no coder, and have no idea how to fix it.

Has anybody seen this happen before?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, I've dealt with this before. You have to specify a `NOBLOGREDIRECT` in your `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.fightify.com' );
```

If there's no site, WP has to redirect visitors somewhere. By default, that's the signup page. Adding that constant tells it where to go.

Comment: @marketer365: since it worked, could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: I've set `NOBLOGREDIRECT` and requests for the main site that should 404 instead redirect 302 -> 200 to the `NOBLOGREDIRECT` URL. Apparently [this is the intended behavior](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13689#comment:26) but it surprised me and it seems wrong.

Comment: The solution to the 404 problem can be found [here](http://frumph.net/2010/06/05/wordpress-3-0-multisite-subdomain-installation-noblogredirect-behavior-fix/): `remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_redirect_404' );`

Comment: @brasofilo been long but still useful. Should be added to the Answer. Without that every 404 request will also be redirected to NOBLOGREDIRECT.

Answer (score 2):

I handle this issue with the [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin.

I run my WP3 Network in subdirectory mode, and just assign domain names via the plugin, including any alternate domains. It's worked well for me, thus far.

Answer (score -2):

If you have moved your site recently, search in your database for any references to the old site and update accordingly. If you're using multisite, this can sometimes be in a few places in the database