# What is the correct way to map multiple domains in a WordPress 4.1 multisite install?

Tags: multisite

I'm aware of [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/my-wordpress-multisite-homepage-redirects-to-signup-page) and others but have not found a definitive answer to how a domain should be set up with multisite so that www and non-www variants behave correctly. I believe I have wildcards set up correctly at the DNS level and the suggested solution to add `define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://www.example.com' );` works for my main site but not other networks in the same install.

I am using the 'WP Multi Network' plugin based on some research which led me to the conclusion that if I am running several domains on one WordPress install, I should be using multiple networks, not just multisite. My Networks and sites are all added with `www` included in the domain field

So what is the correct way to map bare domains without `www` to a multisite install? Are plugins required? Should this all be handled in web server config using rewrites?

Comment: You will need to install the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin to map external domains to any domain in your multi site installation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WordPress Multisite can handle different domains by default - but NOT with alias domains. The settings of each site store the domain. On a default install there is a subdomain or folder-structure. But you can add a single domain.

### Screenshots

For example, the first two sites are with the same domain (default from install) and the third site working with a different domain, external from the default. The last one is a different domain. No plugins or custom source for domain mapping are required.

[image]

Here's a the screenshot of the settings of the last site with a separate domain:

[image]

If you want to reduce the cookie check for each login, add the following constant to `wp-config.php`.

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
```

Otherwise WordPress will always set it to your network’s `$current_site->domain`, which could cause issues in some situations.

### Domain Mapping with Alias

If you require deeper customisation, such as mapping aliases to domains, plugins can help you. WordPress Core hopes to provide Domain Alias Mapping in the future, but until then you can make use of one of the following plugins:

- [Mercator - WordPress multisite domain mapping for the modern era.](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator)
- [WordPress MU Domain Mapping - Map any blog/site on a WordPressMU or
  WordPress 3.X network to an external domain.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)

### WWW vs Non-WWW

I don't have the requisite knowhow about doing this with Non-WWW and WWW urls, but I think this case is slightly different. A domain like www.test.com has the subdomain www. But the www is a synonym for the web and often not interpreted as a subdomain. For all my clients, I rewrite to Non-WWW from the WWW address.

### Hint for Creation of a new site

On the process, to create a new site it is not possible to add a external domain in the input field. Add an random value and after creation of the site, use the edit possibility to add the external site.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you mean that for your clients you do rewrites at the webserver level i.e. before the request reaches WordPress?

Comment: No, this are only the settings on the client side, in the settings of the Multisite installation.

Comment: I am referring to your final sentence "For all my clients, rewrite to Non-WWW from the www address."

Comment: OK. Yes, this is a settings on the domain handling, webspace. But also I add rules to the `.htaccess` of the install.

Comment: @codecowboy thx for the correction of my English!

Comment: Any chance we can get an updated of this answer for WP 4.5 as this appears to be out-of-date.

Comment: Hi Christine, yes, it is possible. But we should wait for WP 4.6, much changes on the network screens. What do you think. In the process we haven't no changes, only on the screenshots.

Comment: @bueltge I agree. If you have the time, I would love an update to this once WP 4.6 is out. We have plans to stop using plugin for domain mapping and use core functions but will await this release before we move forward. Thanks for a great answer nonetheless.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Done, I hope this helps.