# Changing admin sub-domain in Wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping

I have a Wordpress multisite installation where the primary domain name is `domain1.com`. I have two other domain names set as `alpha.domain1.com` and `beta.domain1.com`
which both correspond to `domain2.com` and `domain3.com` when accessed without logged in.

However when I login to any of these two subdomain sites, the admin is always `alpha.domain1.com/wp-admin` and `beta.domain1.com/wp-admin`

How do I make sure that these sub-domains work as `domain2.com/wp-admin` and `domain3.com/wp-admin` when logged in.

Just to add more context, the Siteurl and Home are set as `alpha.domain1.com` and `beta.domain1.com` for these two individual sites on `http://domain1.com/wp-admin/network/site-settings.php`

Comment: Did you use this? - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two commonly used mapping plugins for WordPress. For the next lines we assume you use the free [**WordPress MU Domain Mapping**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) plugin from the WordPress plugin Repository.

From your post I understand you have correctly mapped your domains (you have a dedicated IP or have already set-up the CNAMEs correctly).
You have also correctly mapped your domains alpha.domain1.com to point to domain2.com and made domain2.com the primary domain.

[image: mapping-01]

What you are asking for is possible. You just need to make the correct configuration.

> How to have the **administration pages redirect to the mapped domain**:

[image: mapping02]

- Go to your "*Network Settings*" and click on "*Domain Mapping*".
- Check the two options as at the image above. You don't need to have anything else checked.
- Make sure you **leave unchecked** the
  "*Redirect administration pages to network's original domain*".

If you read the [installation page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/):

> 4. "Redirect administration pages to network's original domain (remote
>      login disabled if this redirect is disabled)" - with this checked, if
>      a user visits their dashboard on a mapped domain it will redirect to
>      the dashboard on the non mapped domain. If you don't want this, remote
>      login will be disabled for security reasons.

Do a **final check** by going to "*Network Settings*", "*Sites*", "*Edit Site*", "*Settings*".
Make sure both your  "*Siteurl*" and "*Home*" fields point to your mapped domain.

[image: mapping-03]

The second mapping plugin is a paid one. You can find information on how to use it [here](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping/).
If that is the one you use, under "*Administration mapping*" you should select 
one of the two options provided.

- "*domain entered by the user*" gives the choice to the mapped site admin to point the administration area to either the mapped domain (domain2.com/wp-admin/) or the original domain (alpha.domain1.com/wp-admin/).
- "*mapped domain*" enables the access to the admin area through the mapped domain (domain2.com/wp-admin/).

Comment: I was facing odd issue of 302 redirect while using wp_signout() function from a ajax call due to the 4rth option enabled in WP MU domain mapping settings. I unchecked it and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need Domain Mapping. Domain mapping allows a blog on a multisite install to serve from any domain name. This way a blog does not have to be a subdirectory of the main install, or a subdomain. The WordPress Default supports Domain Mapping without Alias. Add the Domain in the blog-settings to the blog of the Network administration area.

#### Older Answers

If you have usaged the search on WPSE, maybe you found this helpful [thread 182467](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181914/what-is-the-correct-way-to-map-multiple-domains-in-a-wordpress-4-1-multisite-ins/182467#182467). Read it also, is much helpful.

### Domain Setting with WP Core

You should add the domains to the site settings of each site in the Multisite.

#### Sites

See the follow example screenshot for a additional domain to other domain with directory structure.
[image]

#### Site Info, Domain Setting

To set a domain, edit the site-settings, tab "Info", also a screenshot, helps much more - I think.
[image]

#### Site Settings

Check also the settings, that the URL works for the site and the home-url.
[image]

### Additional Hint

Often is it helpful - but not necessary, to set the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constant to an empty string in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );
```

Otherwise WordPress will always set it to your network's `$current_site->domain`, which could cause issues in some situations.

### WordPress Core and Domain Alias

WordPress can handle different domains inside the core, no additional plugin is necessary. A plugin is only important, if you use alias of a domain. If you will use it, then you have two possibilities form ready usable plugins.

1. [Mercator - WordPress multisite domain mapping for the modern era.](https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator)
2. [WordPress MU Domain Mapping - Map any blog/site on a WordPressMU or WordPress 3.X network to an external domain.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/)