# WordPress Multisite/Network - How to use a subdomain as main blog and subdomain for child sites

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I want to set up a WordPress Multisite where the main admin/blog URL will be on a subdomain, like `admin.mydomain.com`, and then additional sites I create will also be subdomains under `mydomain.com`, such as `site1.mydomain.com`. Instead, in WordPress's Network Setup section, it only allows subdomains like `site1.admin.mydomain.com`. How can I have the main site be `admin.mydomain.com` and child sites be like `site1.mydomain.com`?

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181914/what-is-the-correct-way-to-map-multiple-domains-in-a-wordpress-4-1-multisite-ins/182467#182467), include the links to plugins, that helps on alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways that might work, but both rely on using Apache/NGINX directives.

## Method 1

Setup WordPress MS at mydomain.com, create an admin.mydomain.com site and then redirect mydomain.com to admin.mydomain.com. All additional sites would naturally be subdomains to mydomain.com.

## Method 2

This is basically the inverse of Method 1. You should be able to use a plugin, such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ (it hasn't been updated in a few years, but it still works for me), to map site1.admin.mydomain.com to site1.mydomain.com. The downside is that this will require a manual entry for each new site you add (although this probably could be automated).