# Site redirecting to http://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=example.com

Tags: multisite, redirect, wp-signup

My hosting provider just moved my newly developed website from my testing domain to the definitive domain. But now my site url say's

```
example.com/wp-signup.php?new=example.com
```

And I don't see the page.

The site worked great on my previous domain, the site was moved completely to my main domain, all domain names are changed in the database to my new domain

I've been searching on this problem on Google. I did find these two pages

- [Site Redirecting to wp-signup.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165507/site-redirecting-to-wp-signup-php)
- [My wordpress multisite homepage redirects to signup page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3347/my-wordpress-multisite-homepage-redirects-to-signup-page/3348#3348)

about the same topic. However I've tried the solutions, but they didn't solve my problem.

I tried to change and/or add the way the site handles the domain name without www and with, but both have the same problem, and it didn't affect the outcome.

I now got this in my `wp-config`:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'http://example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', 'http://example.com' );
```

But as a result the page says that there is a problem loading the page and Firefox says the server request is redirected in a way that will never end. A problem that can be caused by disallowing cookies.

Comment: did you change your multisites configuration PRIOR to the movement? This would be the correct behaviour. Is it a real multisite?

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the htaccess file to see if is like the recommended one by WP:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

(See https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess )

I'd also check the 'options' table for the two instances of the site root domain (something like http://www.example.com ). Check that also in the admin Options, General page.

You could also use Firebug debugger in Firefox: use the "Net" tab to see the requests made on loading the page. Click on the first entry and then look at the "Response" tab for possible clues.

Good luck!